# What is meant by speech bias and how to use speechBiasHints in google-actions appResponse

Tags: actions-on-google

I've build an app in "Actions on google" using actions SDK. App request and App response works fine, earlier i've created expectedInput section in AppResponse without using speechBiasingHints, but now i want to use it, and i can't find any information about speechBiasHints.

I mean i need info on:

- What is meant by speech bias
- Can you provide an example on how to use speechBiasingHints

Comment: Perhaps you can describe what **you want to do** rather than assuming a particular field does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Speech biases are influencing the speech to text recognition. So you can for example add here names and other slots etc.

For example you have a Hotel named King Thegeorge you can add it. So google will try to recognize it and deliver the String to you.

but one question, how you use the rest of the inspected input? Do you found a way to give him the possible intents and got them in the request after your response?

you can use them like that (slots is an array, message a string):

```
function answerWithMessage(message,slots){
  let token = {
    "state":null,
    "data":{}
  };

  let jsonResponse = {
        conversationToken: JSON.stringify(token),
        expectUserResponse: true,
        expectedInputs: [
            {
                inputPrompt: {
                    initialPrompts: [
                        {
                            textToSpeech: message
                        }
                    ],
                    noInputPrompts: []
                },
                possibleIntents: [
                    {
                        intent: "actions.intent.TEXT"
                    }
                ],
                speechBiasingHints: slots
            }
        ]
    };
  return JSON.stringify(jsonResponse,null, 4);
}
```

if you create the json response by yourself